# decode character from unicode using java

Tags: java, mysql, unicode

I was unable to insert a chinese character to mysql. So I though of doing this. I have a excel sheet where I have chinese characters. Like `秀昭` and so on.

I got them converted to unicode representations like `\uxxx` using below code which I got from SO, and then I stored in MySQL.

```
private static String escapeNonAscii(String str) {
    List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuilder retStr = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int cp = Character.codePointAt(str, i);
        System.out.println("cp="+cp);
        int charCount = Character.charCount(cp);
        if (charCount > 1) {
            i += charCount - 1; // 2.
            if (i >= str.length()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("truncated unexpectedly");
            }
        }

        if (cp < 128) {
            retStr.appendCodePoint(cp);
        } else {
            retStr.append(String.format("\\u%x", cp));
            arr.add(String.format("\\\\u%x", cp));
        }
    }
    return retStr.toString();
}
```

The values have been stored properly. So now I need to display them back. When I tried

```
System.out.println("\u8BF7\u5728\u6B64\u5904");
```

It gives me proper output like,

```
`请在此`
```

But when I read from DB and did like

```
System.out.println(rs.getString(1).trim().toString() + " from DB");
```

It printed

```
`\u8BF7\u5728\u6B64\u5904`
```

What might be the problem? Have I missed anything? please help.

Comment: How does that surprise you exactly? You _do_ append that in `retStr`; why don't you append the code point directly? Is MySQL unable to store it?

Comment: As far as I know, escape characters only work in string _literals_.

Comment: What's the encoding of your db?

Comment: @Hannes I have set it to utf-8 as per some of the SO threads

Answer (score 0):

Escaped characters will only be processed prior to compiling. To store and retrieve the data from a database, you only have to consider two things: Make sure the data you read had the correct encoding. And when printing the data the correct encoding is set.
If you read data on a windows machine, it is posible you have to use the cp* encodings. Just use a InputStreamReader and set the charset. Now you have the data in the JVM. The internal encoding is some utf-16. Now that you use a type 4 jdbc, you do not have to worry about encoding, except that your database needs a encoding capable to store the data. UTF-8 or Unicode will to the trick. Consult your jdbc documentation for properties to set. Sometimes you have set an encoding explicitly (jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8).
When outputting the data, sometimes the output must have a specific encoding. Normally, your JVM runs with the default system char set but you need another one, for example when rendering a HTML file.